# How many simultaneous select queries can oracle handle

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, oracle11g

I'm building quite complex application in Java, spring 3.2 with WebFlow, Hibernate 3, Oracle 11g and JSF 2.x

In short every user can build his own web pages to create a public website within the application. As everything has to be customizable it is also very generic and every Page is composed of Articles, Translations, Menus, etc all defined by database entities.

Whenever a web page is accessed hibernate execute a series of SELECT queries to collect all the data. This is relatively quick as a Page is loaded in about 10ms from the db, but about 4-5 queries are executed for every page.

So if client1 accesses page A, 5 queries are executed.

My employer is concerned that the number of simultaneous queries could be a problem with the Oracle database. For example if 1000 users will access different pages at the same time about 5000 queries needs to be executed. Note I use the standard Spring connection pool, etc.

My first question is: how many simultaneous SELECT queries can an Oracle database handle? is it really a problem to have too many queries running? I did find some information on concurrent sessions but not about queries, and these shouldn't be concurrent as they are read-only. What is your experience?

I have already implemented some optimization improvements:

1) Some information, like the translations, are stored into memory. But I believe it's more likely for the apache server to run out of memory than for the Oracle database to run out of queries.

2) Where made sense I used a FetchType.JOIN to reduce the number of queries. This works nicely when only a join is involved, but I fear with a too steep increase in complexity (ie. 5 joins and up) the performances would go down to the bottom of the pit. What do you think about this?

In conclusion is this a real problem and if so what is the best strategy to amend it?

Thanks a lot for any help you could give. Let me know if you need any code in particular or the JdbcLogger logs.

p.s. off course to change the infrastructure (spring webflow, jsf, etc) is not an option.

Comment: I'm sure you've done your fair share of reading regarding possible chaching solutions (on various layers)

Comment: Hi I'm for sure not confident with performance of large applications. Hibernate use caching but as for what I can see the same page is cached only for one session and if the user change page that would need to be loaded anew. Also in theory the website could be modified any second by the client so as for now the only thing I store into memory manually are the translations. I don't honestly know what you mean about layers for database queries so I'm gonna check it out now.